# Using a dictionary to store default values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a machine learning program, which has a lot of meta parameters. The intended usage of the program is to research the learning process itself, and therefore I expect I am going to train the model many different times, changing a subset of meta parameters each time, and leave the rest at their default values.

I figured the best way to implement this would be with a default parameter dictionary, for which any value can be overridden by the user.

```
DEFAULT_PARAMETERS={
    "parameter_1": 1,
    "parameter_2": 2,
    #...
}

def main(**kwargs):
    parameters = {}
    for key in DEFAULT_PARAMETERS:
        if key in kwargs:
            parameters[key] = kwargs[key]
        else:
            parameters[key] = DEFAULT_PARAMETERS[key]
```

However, I have never seen people use this method, is there a reason why not? Also, is there a list comprehension sort of syntax that would let me implement the above loop in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I have never seen people use this method

Have you seen enough of other perople's code ? Possibly not (hint: this is a very common pattern, however it's actually implemented)

> is there a reason why not?

Nope, that's just the obvious thing to do here.

> Also, is there a list comprehension sort of syntax that would let me implement the above loop in one line?

For python 3.5+ you could try Vittorio Camisa's solution, but this one works in Python 3.x and latest Python 2.7.x releases:

```
parameters = {k: kwargs.get(k, v) for k, v in DEFAULT_PARAMETERS.items()}
```

Comment: With this solution, though, the returning dict may have not some keys that are only in the `kwargs`

Comment: Indeed - but I assume the defaults should exist in DEFAULT_PARAMETERS for all valid keys so it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

For python 3.5+

```
merged = { **DEFAULT_PARAMETERS, **kwargs }
```

This will do the trick. The `**` syntax expands the dicts.
Be careful! Order matters!

[Related PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers 3.5+ to be more precise

Comment: thanks, forgot about it. I specified it in my answer. :)